# Pull data from an element outside of a loop using a common field while streaming

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I raised a similar question previously but my XML structure has changed / I need to utilise streaming and haven't been able to get this working with my current solution.

I'm looping through XML but some of the fields I need to reference sit outside of my loop and are dependent on an ID from the current loop, there is a common ID field that I can use to match up the elements but I need them to match within the context of the outer loop and not the entire document. I have been trying to use a Key but haven't been able to get it working while streaming / As a test I removed the streaming references I somewhat get what I need but it matches against the entire document rather than my loop.

```
<Date>13/10/2023 15/10/2023 20/10/2023</Date>
```

**XML Structure**

```
<Company><Employee_Stack_Grouped>
<Employee_Stack>
  <Employee>
    <Details>
      <EmployeeID>ABC11111</EmployeeID>
    </Details>
    <Changes sequence="0">
      <ChangeDetails>
        <entryDate>20/10/2023</entryDate>
      </ChangeDetails>
      <Plans>
        <Plan delete="Y">
          <Name>Plan 1</Name>
          <Start>01/01/2023</Start>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 1</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 2</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>67890</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan>
          <Name>Plan 3</Name>
          <Start>01/01/2023</Start>
          <ID>11111</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Interest_Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 4</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>22222</ID>
        </Interest_Plan>
      </Plans>
      <Amounts>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>12345</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>67890</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>11111</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>5000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>22222</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
      </Amounts>
    </Changes>
    <Changes sequence="1">
      <ChangeDetails>
        <entryDate>23/10/2023</entryDate>
      </ChangeDetails>
      <Plans>
        <Plan>
          <Name>Plan 1</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 2</Name>
          <Start>15/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>67890</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan>
          <Name>Plan 3</Name>
          <Start>01/01/2023</Start>
          <ID>11111</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Interest_Plan>
          <Name>Plan 4</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>22222</ID>
        </Interest_Plan>
      </Plans>
      <Amounts>
        <Earning>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>12345</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>2500</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>67890</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>11111</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning>
          <Amount>5000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>22222</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
      </Amounts>
    </Changes>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Details>
      <EmployeeID>ABC222222</EmployeeID>
    </Details>
    <Changes sequence="0">
      <ChangeDetails>
        <entryDate>23/10/2023</entryDate>
      </ChangeDetails>
      <Plans>
        <Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 1</Name>
          <Start>20/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 2</Name>
          <Start>20/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>67890</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Plan>
          <Name>Plan 3</Name>
          <Start>01/01/2023</Start>
          <ID>11111</ID>
        </Plan>
        <Interest_Plan updated="Y">
          <Name>Plan 4</Name>
          <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
          <ID>22222</ID>
        </Interest_Plan>
      </Plans>
      <Amounts>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>12345</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>67890</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>11111</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
        <Earning updated="Y">
          <Amount>5000</Amount>
          <Plan>
            <ID>22222</ID>
          </Plan>
        </Earning>
      </Amounts>
    </Changes>
  </Employee>
</Employee_Stack></Employee_Stack_Grouped></Company>
```

**XSL** uncommenting the Key value throws an error: the node supplied must be in a tree whose root is a document node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:mode streamable="true" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

<xsl:key name="plan" match="Plans/Plan[@updated = 'Y'] | Interest_Plan[@updated = 'Y']" use="ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <File>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee_Stack_Grouped/Employee_Stack/Employee/copy-of()">
            <xsl:variable name="employeeID" select="Details/EmployeeID"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Changes">
                <xsl:variable name="entryDate" select="ChangeDetails/entryDate"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="Amounts/Earning[@updated = 'Y']">
                    <row>
                        <Entry>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$entryDate"/>
                        </Entry>
                        <Employee_Number>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$employeeID"/>
                        </Employee_Number>
                        <Date>
                            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="key('plan', Plan/ID)/Start"/> -->
                        </Date>
                        <Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                        </Amount>
                        <ID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Plan/ID"/>
                        </ID>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </File>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<File>
<row>
    <Entry>20/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC11111</Employee_Number>
    <Date>13/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>1000</Amount>
    <ID>12345</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>20/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC11111</Employee_Number>
    <Date>13/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>1000</Amount>
    <ID>67890</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>20/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC11111</Employee_Number>
    <Date>13/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>5000</Amount>
    <ID>22222</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>23/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC11111</Employee_Number>
    <Date>15/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>2500</Amount>
    <ID>67890</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>23/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC222222</Employee_Number>
    <Date>20/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>1000</Amount>
    <ID>12345</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>23/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC222222</Employee_Number>
    <Date>20/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>1000</Amount>
    <ID>67890</ID>
</row>
<row>
    <Entry>23/10/2023</Entry>
    <Employee_Number>ABC222222</Employee_Number>
    <Date>13/10/2023</Date>
    <Amount>5000</Amount>
    <ID>22222</ID>
</row></File>
```

Note there can be multiple *Employee_Stack_Grouped*, then multiple *Employee* per Employee_Stack, and finally multiple *Changes* per Employee. I essentially need to output any Earnings with an updated Flag but reference the date from the Changes/Plan elements.

I'm not sure if I can achieve this using a Key while streaming? As I can't get this working the other option I am thinking of doing is while looping through the Changes element have another loop that will store any updated Plans in a map, then reference this as I loop through the earnings. any advice on how I can achieve something like this?

Comment: Keys don't work with streaming, and yes, you can, as the Plan elements seem to be before the Employee elements, store the details, easiest with Saxon EE and a capturing accumulator or in a map, and then access the accumulator. See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensions/attributes/capture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a capturing accumulutar (currently Saxon extension, probably standardized in XSLT 4) you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:mode streamable="true" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="plans"/>

<xsl:accumulator name="plans" as="map(xs:integer, map(xs:string,xs:string))" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" saxon:capture="yes" match="Plans/Plan[@updated = 'Y'] | Interest_Plan[@updated = 'Y']"
    select="map:put($value, xs:integer(ID), map:merge(*!map:entry(local-name(), string())))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <File>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee_Stack_Grouped/Employee_Stack/Employee/copy-of()">
            <xsl:variable name="employeeID" select="Details/EmployeeID"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Changes">
                <xsl:variable name="entryDate" select="ChangeDetails/entryDate"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="Amounts/Earning[@updated = 'Y']">
                    <row>
                        <Entry>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$entryDate"/>
                        </Entry>
                        <Employee_Number>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$employeeID"/>
                        </Employee_Number>
                        <Date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('plans')(xs:integer(Plan/ID))?Start"/>
                        </Date>
```

If you don't have the Saxon extension of a "capturing" accumulator you can nevertheless try to store the data in several accumulator and then, one you process an `ID`, create the map entry:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:mode streamable="true" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

<xsl:accumulator name="name" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Plans/Plan[@updated = 'Y']/Name/text() | Interest_Plan[@updated = 'Y']/Name/text()" select="string()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:accumulator name="start" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Plans/Plan[@updated = 'Y']/Start/text() | Interest_Plan[@updated = 'Y']/Start/text()" select="string()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>


<xsl:accumulator name="plans" as="map(xs:integer, map(xs:string,xs:string))" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Plans/Plan[@updated = 'Y']/ID/text() | Interest_Plan[@updated = 'Y']/ID/text()"
    select="map:put($value, xs:integer(.), map { 'Start' : accumulator-before('start'), 'Name' : accumulator-before('name') })"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <File>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee_Stack_Grouped/Employee_Stack/Employee/copy-of()">
            <xsl:variable name="employeeID" select="Details/EmployeeID"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Changes">
                <xsl:variable name="entryDate" select="ChangeDetails/entryDate"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="Amounts/Earning[@updated = 'Y']">
                    <row>
                        <Entry>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$entryDate"/>
                        </Entry>
                        <Employee_Number>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$employeeID"/>
                        </Employee_Number>
                        <Date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('plans')(xs:integer(Plan/ID))?Start"/>
                        </Date>
```

You will need to test yourself whether that approach works way back with 9.7 EE, as I said, the final XSLT 3 version was produced after that release and only 9.8 and later are supposed to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution, this seems to do what I need. Can you help me understand this bit "(Plan/ID))?Start" - Is this just a ternary TF for if the ID is found within Plans return the Start? Additionally, if that field had a namespace how would that be handled? I assume test:Start would not work, it would need masked in someway?

Comment: If you want to use maps I thought you would know how to do that in XPath 3.1, read https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#lookup-operator for the details if you don't know the `?` lookup operator. In `select="map:put($value, xs:integer(ID), map:merge(*!map:entry(local-name(), string())))"/>` I just "map" each child element to a map entry, based on the local name of the child element, so you get map entries of e.g. the name `Start` and the `?Start` select that map entry.

Comment: Testing this locally within XMLSpy works but within my application which uses SaxonEE 9.7 an error is thrown. "The xsl: accumulator-rule/@select expression for a streaming accumulator must be motionless. There is more than one consuming operand: {xs:integer(ID)} and {map:merge(...)}"

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: I have assumed you are using a version and edition of Saxon that is supported and is known to handle the XSLT 3.0 spec (from 2017) (i.e. 9.8 or later are the releases to support the final XSLT 3.0 spec but the currently supported versions are 12, 11, 10) and the Saxon specific extension I have used (https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/attributes/capture.html, introduced in 9.9). I am afraid in terms of streaming and exact rules it doesn't make much sense to try EE 9.7 as it was released before XSLT 3.0 was finalized. And my use of `saxon:capture` would require 9.9 or later

Comment: Thanks for your help with this anyway. I'm unfortunately stuck with the 9.7 limitation, i'll need to figure out another method but this was very helpful.

Comment: @user2337472, I have added an alternative without using `saxon:capture`, using several accumulators instead to fetch the `Name` and `Start` and then, once `ID` is being processed, to store the two values in a map entry. That should in theory work back with 9.8 EE and later but I have only tested with 10.9 EE. Check yourself what 9.7 EE does, perhaps you are lucky and it does what you need.